# Convert generic IList into an array of a subtype

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, covariance

(please don't ask why I'm doing this - I'm interfacing with some legacy code)

I have an `IList<Animal>` and I want to convert it to an array of a sub-type of Animal (e.g. Leopard), but the sub-type is not known at compile time - it's passed in as a parameter.

[edit: it's guaranteed the list will only contain leopards]

I have found a way that works:

`var myArray = (object[])new ArrayList(animals.ToList()).ToArray(animalType)`

the caller will then cast myArray to `Leopard[]` for instance.

is there a better solution?

Comment: So what about the Elephants in the List<>?

Comment: `animals.OfType<Elephant>()` if you have different types in the list or `animals.Cast<Elephant>()` is one way, but it's not clear exactly what you are doing here - it smells a bit fishy.

Comment: @Dennis_E animals.ToArray() will generate an array of animals, not an array of leopards

Comment: @DavidG I can't use Cast<T> because I don't know the type at compile type. I agree it's fishy but I'm trying to inter operate with legacy code that requires this interface.

Comment: @Andy I was just about to delete that comment.

Comment: If array is large and you want to optimize memory usage, try using some code-generation to build expression, calling Array.ConvertAll static method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[animals.Count];
animals.CopyTo(animalArray, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to show here. this is creating an array of Animals not an array of Leopards

Comment: Same logic, just substitute your Leopard for my Animal - just added another answer demonstrating

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Leopard : Animal
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new List<Animal>
        {
            new Leopard { Name = "Bob" },
            new Leopard { Name = "Jeff" },
            new Leopard { Name = "Bill" },
            new Leopard { Name = "Dave" }
        };

        Leopard[] leopardArray = new Leopard[animals.Count];
        animals.CopyTo(leopardArray, 0);

        Console.Write(leopardArray.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this wouldn't work as-is because I don't know the destination type until runtime. However, if I used `Array.CreateInstance(animalType, animals.Count)` then your solution would work. It would presumably be more performant than my solution but is 2 lines instead of 1, so I'm unsure which I prefer.